# Linked Service with Azure Active Directory - Password

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory, and trying to create a new Linked Service to a Azure SQL Database. However I'm getting an error trying to do so. Below is the ADF linked service creation template.

[image]

I'm using a service account, which works when connecting to the Azure SQL database, through Management Studio, using authentication method Azure Active Diretory - Password. Tho I am not able to connect to it with linked service. So I'm asking if it's possible to do with AAD - Password, and if so how?

I am getting the error

```
Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. Cannot open server "emailadress.com" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Which makes me wonder if username can contain '@', as the error does not display any of the username letters before @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to Azure SQL database with service principle in ADF linked service, select the **Authentication type as Service Principle** in the drop-down as mentioned by @Nandan.

And to use the **Service principle** with Azure AD application token authentication you will need **Tenant**, **Service principal ID** (Application ID), and **Service principal key** (Application Key).

[image]

Get these values by creating an Azure Active Directory application. Follow this MS document to register an application with AAD and [create a service principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

Also, refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#service-principal-authentication) for prerequisites for using Service Principal authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ADF doesnt support AD auth for Azure SQL database:
[image]

You are using SQL auth as drop down and in that using AD account because of which it is failing